# Dynamics menu php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am quite new in php

I would like to make a website where all pages has a default menu with 4 choices.
Then, depending of the choice a specific sub-menu will be showed in a new page (including the main menu).

I could obviously do something like:

```
index.php - main-menu - sub-menu1
index.php - main-menu - sub-menu2
index.php - main-menu - sub-menu3
```

But, is there any other way I can make a single page "sub-menu" and show different "sub-menu 'div' " so that I dont need to create a new page for each sub-menu?

Maybe I should use smarty php template engine?
Could anybody put me in the right way or give any suggestions? either advice`?

Exemple: if my index is something like:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<?php include ("main-menu.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Do I have to create different page for each submenu? Like...

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <?php include ("main-menu.php"); ?>
    <?php include ("submenu1.php"); ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

or I can create  page "submenu" and show that specific submenu I want base on a page title for exemple?

Comment: an include with some if statements in it is a simple old school way....if I understand what you're asking, which I'm not sure I do.

Comment: U are right, I updated my question. It really hard to explain when you are  a noob.